# Multiple non-conjunctive conditions for list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 4-tuples. I want to check if it has at least one tuple with its 3rd element is equal to 'JJ' and at least one tuple with its 4th element is equal to 'nsubj'. However, these don't necessarily have to be the same tuple.

So doing something like -

```
if (any([tup for tup in parse_tree[i] if (tup[2] == 'JJ' and tup[3] == 'nsubj')])):
```

is wrong.

Instead if you do

```
if (any([tup for tup in parse_tree[i] if (tup[2] == 'JJ' or tup[3] == 'nsubj')])):
```

You'll get lists  which satisfy at least one condition but not both.

The only way I could think to resolve this was by doing this-

```
if any([tup for tup in parse_tree[i] if tup[2] == 'JJ']) and any([tup for tup in parse_tree[i] if tup[3] == 'nsubj']):
```

Is there a way to do this with  only one list?

Comment: While it won't solve your problem, using generator expressions will reduce its runtime. Drop the `[]` from your last statement - `any` will stop as soon as an element is `True`, but the `[]` force all elements to be created at the moment.

Comment: Having a list comprehension with state in is a bad idea. The simplest way to do this is a straightforward loop and flags for each thing you're looking for.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Isn't that unpythonic?

Comment: No more than trying to jam this into one unreadable line!

Answer (score 1):

You could group all 3rd and 4th elements from the tuples in the list into new tuples in another list using `zip` and then check for the elements directly from these new tuples:

```
# say lst is your original list

new_lst = zip(*lst)
if 'JJ' in new_lst[2] and 'nsubj' in new_lst[3]:
     # your code
```

Of course, if creating a new list from your original list is allowed

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a purely boolean plus `any/all` solution to this. Without primitives, you can solve this with a custom comparison object that keeps state.

```
class MultiComp(object):
    def __init__(self, *conditions):
        self._conditions = conditions
        self._results = [False] * len(conditions)

    def __bool__(self):
        return all(self._results)

    __nonzero__ = __bool__

    def digest(self, elem):
        for idx, condition in enumerate(self._conditions):
            if not self._results[idx] and condition(elem):
                self._results[idx] = True
        return self

comp = MultiComp(lambda tup: tup[2] == 'JJ', lambda tup: tup[3] == 'nsubj')
any(tup for tup in ttuple if bool(comp.digest(tup)))
```

Note that this is more than ten times *slower* than properly evaluating both conditions.

Comparison class:

```
In [215]: %%timeit
   .....: comp = MultiComp(lambda tup: tup[2] == 'JJ', lambda tup: tup[3] == 'nsubj')
   .....: any(tup for tup in ttuple if bool(comp.digest(tup)))
   .....:
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.6 µs per loop
```

Properly using generators:

```
In [216]: %%timeit
   .....: any(tup[2] == 'JJ' for tup in ttuple) and any(tup[3] == 'nsubj' for tup in ttuple)
   .....:
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.26 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like using generators(which is more efficient) instead of lists per se.

Is there any specific reason you need it to be done with only one list?

```
if any(True for tuple_list in list_of_tuple_lists if any(True for t in tuple_list if t[2]=='JJ') and any(True for t in tuple_list if t[3] == 'nsubj'))
```

And to match your naming:

```
if any(True for tuple_list in parse_tree[i] if any(True for t in tuple_list if t[2]=='JJ') and any(True for t in tuple_list if t[3] == 'nsubj'))
```

That code works for all cases. Simple test:

```
import random
import time

none = [(1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,4)] # none of the conditions
first = [(1,2,3,4),(1,2,'JJ',4),(1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,4)]# only first of the conditions
second = [(1,2,3,4),(1,2,'test',4),(1,2,4,'nsubj'),(1,2,3,4)]# only second of the conditions
both = [(1,2,'JJ',4),(1,2,'test',4),(1,2,3,'nsubj'),(1,2,3,4)]# both of the conditions in different tuples
same = [(1,2,'JJ','nsubj'),(1,2,'test',4),(1,2,2,4),(1,2,3,4)]# both of the conditions in same tuple
possible_tuples=[none,first,second,both,same]


def our_check(list_of_tuple_lists):
    if any(True for tuple_list in list_of_tuple_lists if any(True for t in tuple_list if t[2]=='JJ') and any(True for t in tuple_list if t[3] == 'nsubj')):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def our_check_w_lists(list_of_tuple_lists):
    if any([True for tuple_list in list_of_tuple_lists
           if any([True for t in tuple_list if t[2]=='JJ']) and any([True for t in tuple_list if t[3] == 'nsubj'])]):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def third_snippet(list_of_tuple_lists):
    if any([tup for tup in list_of_tuple_lists if tup[2] == 'JJ']) and any([tup for tup in list_of_tuple_lists if tup[3] == 'nsubj']):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def test(func):
    test_cases = []
    for n in range(100000):
        test_list=[]
        for i in range(10):
            test_list.append(random.choice(possible_tuples))
        expected = False
        if both in test_list or same in test_list:
            expected = True

        test_case = expected, test_list
        test_cases.append(test_case)
    start = time.clock()
    for expected, case_list in test_cases:
        if expected != func(case_list):
            print('%s, Fail for: %s'%(func,case_list))
            return False
    end = time.clock()
    print('function:%s, %f'%(func, end-start))

test(our_check)
test(our_check_w_lists)
test(third_snippet)
```

This test results shows execution time difference between using generators and list comprehension for just only 10-tuples long list.

```
function:<function our_check at 0x00000000028CE7B8>, 0.378369
function:<function our_check_w_lists at 0x00000000031472F0>, 1.270924
<function third_snippet at 0x00000000031E0840>, Fail for: [[...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but isn't that basically doing exactly what I'm doing but putting it in a function?

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu I just put in the function for testing. You can use the short snippet above where list_of_tuple_lists would be parse_tree[i] to match your code. It isn't doing the same since it only uses generators and isn't creating any list. Any() statement with generator as argument will stop once it gets True. Using [] list comprehension will cause to generate that full list regardless where and when conditions would be satisfied. Besides your third snippet fails in my test.

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu I've updated my answer to show difference in perfomance between using generators and list comprehension.

Comment: Wow, that's a big difference. I have to admit, I didn't notice that you removed the list object from the any() function in your answer. However, my main issue was writing what I wanted to in one line, as one condition. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu well it is in one line as single if: if any(True for tuple_list in list_of_tuple_lists if any(True for t in tuple_list if t[2]=='JJ') and any(True for t in tuple_list if t[3] == 'nsubj')) I've just formatted it to be more readable on the site in snippets and moved to function to test perfomance. You can just put it inline in your statement just fine.